# whether $X^\perp_0$ and $X_0$ are complete.

Tags: functional-analysis

$X=C[0,1]$ with inner product $\langle x,y\rangle=\int_{0}^{1} x(t)\overline{y(t)} dt$

$X_0=\{x\in C[0,1]:\int_{0}^{1} t^2x(t)dt=0\}$ and $X^\perp_0$ be the orthogonal complement of $X_0$. I need to find out whether $X^\perp_0$ and $X_0$ are complete.

let $x_n(t)$ be a sequence in $X_0$ converging to $x_0(t)$ we know that will be unoform convergence so $\lim\int_{0}^{1} t^2x_n(t)dt=0=\int_{0}^{1}t^2\lim x_n(t) dt=\int_{0}^{1}t^2x_0(t) dt\Rightarrow x_0(t)\in X_0$ so $X_0$ is complete.

I have no idea about $X^\perp_0$ could any one tell me?

Comment: The norm on $X$ is the $L^2$-norm and the $L^2$ convergence doesn't imply the $L^{\infty}$ convergence so how do you know that $x_n$ converges uniformly?

Answer (score 1):

Consider function $z(t)=t^2$ and the linear functional 
$$
f:(C([0,1],\Vert\cdot\Vert_2)\to\mathbb{C}:x\mapsto \langle z,x\rangle
$$
Obviously $f$ if continuous, hence its kernel is closed subspace of codimension $1$. Since $f(z)\neq 0$,  then $X=\ker f\oplus\mathbb{C}z$. Note $z\in X_0^\perp$, and $X\oplus X_0^\perp\subset X$. Hence $X=X_0\oplus X_0^\perp$, and $X_0^\perp=X/\ker f=\mathbb{C}$. Thus $X_0^\perp$ is complete. If $X_0$ would be complete, then $X$ would be also complete because as direct sum of complete spaces. But $X$ is not complete, so does $X_0$.

Comment: I just dont understand how $X/kerf$ is defined and why that is equal to $X_0$ perp

Comment: $X/\ker f$ is a quotient space, for its definition see this notes (http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6338/summer08/section6a.pdf)

Comment: @Norbert:given space X is not a hilbert space ,then,how could you decompose it as a direct sum of orthogonal subspaces